# What is a localiser back-course approach and how does it work?

Tags: landing, ils

What does back-course approach mean ? How much signal strength should the back lobe of ILS should have in order to trace it and commence landing. How common is this type of landing for a pilot. What all instruments are required for this type of landing?

Comment: Hello Huntkil, welcome to Aviation.SE

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A localizer back course is simply flying on the back side of the localizer to the runway.  How a localizer works is it sends out two signal lobes:  one at 90Hz and the other at 150Hz.  The localizer needle in the airplane compares the relative strength it receives from both lobes and then shows a deflection.

See this figure from the [Instrument Flying Handbook (2015)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/) published by the FAA.
[image: Figure 9-33]

Notice the top left of the picture shows the same lobes on the same side of the runway.  Now imagine flying the front-course, the blue lobe is on the right.  If you are flying the back-course, the blue lobe would be on the left.

The localizer needle doesn't know if you are on the front-course or the back-course and will show the same deflection for both situations.  The problem comes in for the back-course is that the needle deflection is deflected the wrong way.

---

To answer your questions.

1. What does back-course mean?  It simply means you are flying on the opposite of the localizer signal.  If there is a back-course published, the signal strength will be strong enough to fly the approach as required.
2. How common is a back-course approach?  There are currently 69 back-course approaches in the United States.  There are approximately 1,893 ILS approaches.  This is around 3.5% of back-course approaches as compared to ILS approaches.
3. The same flight and navigation instruments required to fly a front-course ILS is required to fly a back-course ILS.

---

From a technique standpoint.  Whenever I fly a back-course approach, irrespective of whether I am using an HSI or VOR receiver, I will always set in the front course.  For pilots that use an HSI this will provide for "positive sensing" meaning the needle will deflect correctly.  For pilots using a VOR, the needle will shade bottom numbers that correspond to heading that need to be flown to get back onto the back-course approach.

[image: VOR Indicator]

If this was a back-course approach, notice that the needle is deflected to the right.  Conventional wisdom says you need to turn away from the needle to re-intercept.  I say to select a heading under the needle to fly.  That heading will be approximately 120°.  Take a look at the heading indicator and determine that you most likely need to turn left to re-intercept the back-course.  Try it and you will see it works.  Conversely, I also teach the same concept for an ILS except the heading to fly is on top of the VOR indicator instead of on the bottom.