# What is the difference in purpose of the 1:40 Obstacle Identification Surface and the 1:50 clearance plane for an ILS glideslope?

Tags: ils, radio-navigation, obstacle-clearance

I have found references to the [Obstacle Identification Surface (OIS)](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/62501/what-is-an-obstacle-identification-surface-and-why-would-a-pilot-intentionally-p), which is approximately a 152ft/NM slope from the end of the runway (1.43 degrees, 1:40 rise/run) and a 1:50 clearance plane noted in [the illustration in this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33545/what-is-a-localiser-back-course-approach-and-how-does-it-work):

> [image: illustration in said answer]

1:50 is 121.5ft/NM, so they clearly aren't one in the same.

Why are there both? What is the difference in purpose?

Comment: Are you sure the 2nd link is the right one? I don't see the 1:50 mention.

Comment: @ymb1 It's in one of the bubbles in the graphic of the accepted answer.